# How to enter East Jerusalem and who controls the separation with the western part

Tags: customs-and-immigration, israel, security, borders, jerusalem

Can non-Muslim people from non-Muslim countries (EU) enter the part of Jerusalem where the famous [mosque with yellow top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dome_of_the_Rock) is located?

Are the police (or guards) at the entrance Israeli or Palestinian?

Who is the owner and in control of the area between Jerusalem and East Jerusalem, which on map seems to be out of Israeli lands? What laws apply? Is there a border and passport control like crossing from one country to another?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jerusalem is no longer divided (it was divided between Jordan and Israel between 1948 and 1967). Israel controls all of it, and there are no check points or border control anywhere in the city.

There are *security* checkpoints at the entrance to the Temple Mount, but they're there to keep the **Israelis** (and weapons) out, not the foreigners (as opposed to what you might have heard, even though Israelis control all of the city, it is the *Israelis*, Jews in particular, who are banned from the Temple Mount). Most tourist can get in without a problem. Dress accordingly. On Friday's, religious holidays or when there're some occasional security tensions and alerts, some restrictions may be in place (usually for the Israeli/Palestinian Muslims coming to pray, but may also affect tourists).

The yellow capped building is not the Al Aqsa mosque, its the Dome of the Rock and it's not a mosque at all. Al Aqsa mosque is the gray and unattractive building in the corner of the Temple Mount compound, right on top of the Western Wall.

Comment: After your comment I looked for Dome of the Rock but I do not understand what it is. What is it? It says it's a shrine but, what's the difference between that and the mosque there? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Also very importantly, how is the travel between Jerusalem and Mount Scopus in between which there seems to be land out of Israel on map? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Phil: I think you should ask that as a question on its own.

Comment: For purposes of visiting, treat the Dome of the Rock as a mosque. It's a Muslim holy site, and you will need to dress appropriately and behave appropriately if you visit it.

Comment: According to wiki page of 'Dome of Rock' translates to 'Masjid Qubbat As-Sakhrah'. And masjid in Arabic means mosque.

Comment: @Phil its not a mosque, initially it was built to cover the "rock" - the piece of the mountain from which Muhammad was believed to jump to the sky with his horse. Accidently he is believed to do so on the same rock where Abraham almost sacrificed Isaak, and the same place is also believed to be the Temple sanctuary. It may be used for prayer, but the center of the building is what it is about, while mosques generally built for prayers to face Mecca. That's not the case for the Dome of the Rock.

Comment: @Phil and yes, don't let this semantic distinction treat it any differently, if at all - you would need to be showing much more respect to Islam in the Dome of the Rock, than in any mosque.

Comment: @Phil, missed your question about Mount Scopus. Mount Scopus is within the Jerusalem municipal limts, and has been part of the State of Israel since its creation. I don't know what map you're looking it. The compound on Mount Scopus is the Northern campus of the Hebrew University of Jerusalem (the original location of the University, established in 1930's, until it expanded to the Givat Ram neighborhood later).

Comment: Hello @littleadv! Thank you once again very much. I was just trying to learn more about things on wikipedia so after your responses, whilst reading about Jerusalem and the rock subject, I saw the map there which separates Mount Scopus from Jerusalem's borders. So, I got confused.

Comment: @Phil keep in mind that Jerusalem is a highly politicized topic, and there's a lot of disinformation going on. The map you're referring to is probably the map of the city partition of 1948 - the old city and the eastern neighborhoods were part of Jordan, while the western parts of the city were part of Israel. Mount Scopus was part of Israel, but surrounded by Jordanian territory. This is no longer relevant to anything really, since 1967. The city is united and under Israeli control.

Comment: The Israelis are technically not in control of Temple Mount. There is an agreement that the Waqf maintains control. Additionally, Jews are not allowed on the Mount for religious reasons, not political.

Comment: @Imray of course they're in control. Waqf manages the area, but the police can enter any time, and does so to restore order on many occasions. Jews are not allowed for political reasons. Even this very week an Israeli politician (religious one, mind you) was not allowed to enter by the police because last time it happened the Arabs used it as an excuse to start a war.

Comment: @littleadv You're right, Waqf only has _day-to-day_ and administrative control while the Israelis do have _military_ control (thank God!)

Comment: @Imray that's not "military" control, that's called "sovereignty". Look it up. Waqf is basically an HOA.

Answer (score 12):

The Dome of the Rock is located on the [Temple Mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Mount). The Temple Mount is located in the [old city of Jerusalem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_City_of_Jerusalem). The Temple Mount can be visited and you don't need a special permit for this.

There are a couple of gates in the old city of Jerusalem. All the gates are controlled by the Israeli police. These are security checks. However If you are not a Muslim you do have to enter the site through the "Bab al-Maghariba". This gate is located on the Western Wall Plaza. In fact if you are standing in front of the Western Wall, it is the covered bridge you can see on your right hand side. You have to pass through metal detectors and bags are x-rayed. Note that you can exit the Temple Mount through one of the other gates.

The Temple Mount is a highly religious site. Thus some decent dress is required.

Comment: I believe the bridge has been closed for renovations (or going to be closed soon), so the entry should be from the old city, but better check when there what's the current status.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: during Ramadan we were not allowed to enter Temple Mount.

Comment: Who is the "we" that you are talking about?

Comment: A friend and me... How is this related to the question?

Comment: If you don't say who you are, the questioner couldn't reasonably deduce whether it applied to him or not.

Comment: Yes, DJ is right. I was looking at the subject from the perspective of an non-muslim non-muslim-nation eu citizen. ;-) Thank you.

Comment: Well, non-muslim EU-citizen

Comment: Who blocked you from entering? The Waqf or Israel?